# Finding a substring in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-re

I have an issue and can't solve it, I have a dynamic list `data` (request data from web) that contains multiple lists, and each one contains strings, integers, etc., but I need the one which contains a specific text `StreamCache`. and just one and only one list in `data` contains the string `StreamCache`, which I store it in a new list. Almost all time my code works perfectly, but when it finds a list with a string like `StreamCache@abnsdj12` or `StreamCache*mljsgfn525`, that are essentially the lists I need, my code doesn't work, just because `StreamCache` doesn't match exactly with `StreamCache@kahsgsgh5` or so, I tried with list comprehension, regular expressions, but nothing works. Can someone help me?
These are my solutions:

```
# Works only if 'StreamCache' matchs exactly with the iterable
temp1 = [i for i in data if 'StreamCache' in i]
################ Solution 2 that doesn't work at all
search = 'StreamCache'
for element in data:
    if isinstance(element, list):
        new = [i for i in element]
        z = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(k) for k in new))
        result = re.findall(z, search)
```

Hope you can help me with this.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if `StreamCache` is part of any string in the list, which you could do with something like this:

```py
[l for l in data if any('StreamCache' in s for s in l)]
```

If `StreamCache` always occurs at the beginning of the string, this would be more efficient:

```py
[l for l in data if any(s.startswith('StreamCache') for s in l)]
```

Comment: The first solution works perfect! Thank you! And yeah, always occurs an the beggining of the string but `s` always was created as a list so startswith didn't work, but thank you anyway!

Comment: @noname22 I'm glad I could help. It wasn't 100% clear as to what your data looked like, hence the second option.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd approach you attempted only returns `[StreamCache]` because the content you searching in is only `StreamCache` and regex object is `<element 1>|<element 2>|....`, did you mean to find the `StreamCache.*` string inside an string like below example?

```
a|abc|StreamCache*mljsgfn777|123|StreamCache|aweafwfa|asfwqwdq|StreamCache@abnsdj12|somestring|StreamCache*mljsgfn525
```

If so, I think you got the argument reverse by mistake, which the regex object is the first parameter and the search content is the second parameter. Below is an example that seems to provide the expected result for me

```
search = 'a|abc|StreamCache*mljsgfn777|123|StreamCache|aweafwfa|asfwqwdq|StreamCache@abnsdj12|somestring|StreamCache*mljsgfn525' # search content
z = re.compile('StreamCache[^|]*|') # regex object
search_result = list(filter(lambda x: x, re.findall(z, search))) # use filter to remove empty strings
# search_result here would contain ['StreamCache*mljsgfn777', 'StreamCache', 'StreamCache@abnsdj12', 'StreamCache*mljsgfn525']
```